# Is it possible to export a single table from Azure sql database, then directly save into azure blob storage without downloading it to local disk

Tags: sql, database, azure

I've tried to use SSMS, but it requires a temporary location for the BacPac file which is local. But i don't want to download it to local, would like to export a single table directly to Azure Blob storage.

Comment: Refer [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=SSMS#back-up-database). Might be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, we could import table data from the csv file stored in blob storage. But didn't find a way to export the table data to Blob Storage as  csv file directly.

You could think about using [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction).

It can achieve that , please reference bellow tutorials:

1. [Copy and transform data in Azure SQL Database by using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)
2. [Copy and transform data in Azure Blob storage by using Azure Data
   Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage)

Using Azure SQL database as the Source, and choose the table as dataset:

Source dataset:

[image]

Source:

[image]

Using Blob storage as Sink, and choose the DelimitedText as the sink format file:

Sink dataset:

[image]

Sink:

[image]

Run the pipeline and you will get the csv file in Blob Storage.

Also thanks for the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=SSMS#back-up-database) @Hemant Halwai provided for us.